# infinite while loop that wont subtract numbers

Tags: matlab, loops, while-loop

I'm trying to calculate the number of burns it takes for meters to get below 35 meters. I am having trouble with the while loop. It is infinite and i'm trying to keep the subtraction going until it is less than 35 meters but it wont subtract anything.

```
% Inputs
burns = input('Enter the distance to be traveled in kilometers: ');
meters = burns*1000;
count = 0;
left = meters;

 % While loop
while  left >= 35;
    count = count+1;
    travel = meters*0.6;
    left = meters-travel;
    fprintf('Burns: Traveled %.2f meters\n \t\t %.2f meters left\n',travel,left);
end
fprintf('You made it to Jupiter in %d burns\n',count);
```

Comment: because what you wanted to write is this: `left = left-travel;`?

Comment: Thank you! I made the changes. I had to change the meters in (travel = meter-travel) as well. When i changed it to left, it worked correctly.

Comment: Do you know how far I had to read into this question to figure out that you were talking about spacecraft and not medical emergencies?